# Not understanding why I am getting this error

Tags: sql, database

This is the code I did

```
  SELECT TOP 5  ContactName FROM Customers
INNER JOIN [Order Details]ON OrderId = 
CustomerID
INNER JOIN Orders ON ProductID = OrderID
WHERE UnitPrice >= 25000
ORDER BY ContactName ASC
```

But this is the error I am getting

```
   Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Ambiguous column name 'orderID'
```

Can someone explain to me why I am getting this error.

This is what I am trying to do is show the most recent five orders that were purchased from a customer who has spent more than $25,000

So i am assuming to use order,product,and customer.

Comment: Additional to all the comments below, it's bad practice to have table names that include a space. E.g `Order Details` should really be `OrderDetails`.

Comment: Well that is how the table is already name dbo. Order Detail so there is nothing much I can do with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably an `OrderID` column in both your `Order Details` and your `Orders` table, and SQL Server doesn't know which one to take.

Solution: specify which one you want to use by putting the table name in front of it:
`Orders.OrderID` instead of just `OrderID`

So your query would look like this then:

```
SELECT TOP 5  ContactName FROM Customers
INNER JOIN [Order Details]ON Orders.OrderId = 
CustomerID
INNER JOIN Orders ON ProductID = Orders.OrderID
WHERE UnitPrice >= 25000
ORDER BY ContactName ASC
```

Answer (score 3):

The column `OrderID` exists in both tables.

Comment: It seems strange that you are trying to join OrderID to CustomerID and ProductID. They would need to be the same for the query to return results.

Comment: This is what I am trying to do is show the most recent five orders that were purchased from a customer who has spent more than $25,000

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly you have the field `orderID` in both the `Details` and the `Orders` table.

Clarify it with either `Orders.orderID` or `Details.orderID`.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 OrderID columns across the tables.
You can remove the ambiguity with aliases (like this) or use `Orders.OrderID`

```
SELECT TOP 5 C.ContactName 
FROM 
  Customers C
  INNER JOIN 
  [Order Details] OD ON C.OrderId = OD.CustomerID
  INNER JOIN
   Orders O ON OD.ProductID = O.OrderID
WHERE O.UnitPrice >= 25000 -- or OD?
ORDER BY C.ContactName ASC
```

Note: did you mean to joion Customers and [Order Details] like using Customers.OrderId?

Comment: @Balamurugan K: .. er I copied too much of the question

Answer (score 0):

When you `JOIN` multiple tables in the same query, you need to differentiate any columns which have the same name in multiple tables. Otherwise, how would the query engine know which one you're talking about?

You can do this either by prefixing the column name with `<table name>.` or `<table alias>.`.

For example:

```
SELECT TOP 5
    C.ContactName
FROM
    Customers C    -- Customers is aliased as "C"
INNER JOIN [Order Details] OD ON
    OD.OrderId = C.CustomerID
INNER JOIN Orders O ON
    OD.ProductID = O.OrderID
WHERE
    OD.UnitPrice >= 25000
ORDER BY
    C.ContactName ASC
```

Another important question... are you sure that you're joining on the correct columns there? It looks **really** wrong.

Finally, if this is for a homework assignment, please make sure that you tag it as such with the "homework" tag.

Comment: This is what I am trying to do is show the most recent five orders that were purchased from a customer who has spent more than $25,000

Comment: Has spent more than $25,000 on one item? In one order? Over all time? Over the past year? IN any event, I think that several of the answers here have properly explained the problem related to this question. If you are still having other issues related to your query then please create a new question for those.

Answer (score 0):

In your references to OrderId, you need to figure out which table you are pulling the orderId column from.  (In some cases, you can just pick either table).  Let's call that table .

In your query, replace orderId with .orderId.